# How do i remove the empty lines from table?

Tags: tables

I am currently trying to remove the lines in the table, that doesn't contain anything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}| }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Title} \\
    \hline
    Window size: 9 &  Results & Window size: 15 &  Results \\ 
    \hline
    Accuracy &  0.70 & Accuracy &  0.60  \\
    Validation accuracy&    0.19 & Validation accuracy&    0.16 \\  
    \hline
    Window size: 32 &  Results  \\
    \hline
    Accuracy &  0.14 \\
    Validation accuracy&    0.07 \\   
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do i remove the empty lines in this table?

Is there a simple way to remove it?..

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @dexteritas you are right..  I added that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\cline{x-y}` to make horizontal lines for specified columns.

There was one unused column, so I removed the last `p{3cm}|`.

For 4 equal columns you can also use: `*4{p{3cm}|}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ |*4{p{3cm}|} }
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Title} \\
        \hline
        Window size: 9 &  Results & Window size: 15 &  Results \\ 
        \hline
        Accuracy &  0.70 & Accuracy &  0.60  \\
        Validation accuracy&    0.19 & Validation accuracy&    0.16 \\  
        \hline
        Window size: 32 &  Results  \\
        \cline{1-2}
        Accuracy &  0.14 \\
        Validation accuracy&    0.07 \\   
        \cline{1-2}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem is not the long lines, but the design of the table leaving unnecessary empty cells and redundant row headers. The solution is redesign the table. I suggest strongly also avoid **all** vertical lines and use the commands of `booktabs` package. Then you can use `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline` for horizontal lines in selected columns only.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption*{Meaningful Title About the Results}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.0]cc}
    \toprule
    {Window size} &  Accuracy &  {Validation}\\
    \cmidrule(rl){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-3} 
    % ... or simply \midrule
     9 & 0.70 & 0.19\\
    15 & 0.60 & 0.16\\
    32 & 0.14 & 0.07\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```